# Don't know what to do? python

Tags: python, typeerror

```
import scipy as sp

atomos=open("Átomo.txt", 'r')

deltaX=[]
deltaY=[]
deltaZ=[]
d=0

def dist(xf, xi, yf, yi,zf, zi):
    d=sp.sqrt((xf-xi)*(xf-xi)+(yf-yi)*(yf-yi)+(zf-zi)*(zf-zi))
    return d

for colunas in atomos:

    coluna_limpa=colunas.strip().split("\t")
    deltaX.append(coluna_limpa[1])
    deltaY.append(coluna_limpa[2])
    deltaZ.append(coluna_limpa[3])
print(deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ)

d= dist(deltaX[0], deltaX[9],deltaY[0], deltaY[9], deltaZ[0], deltaZ[9] )

print("A distância do segmento formado pelos atomos é de ", d)


File "<ipython-input-5-e2b6e08387d0>", line 11, in dist
    d=sp.sqrt((xf-xi)*(xf-xi)+(yf-yi)*(yf-yi)+(zf-zi)*(zf-zi))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Evidently the objects referenced by those variables are strings, and so you cannot subtract them. Perhaps you want to convert them to numbers first. Since you've given no indication of what your program is supposed to do, I can only guess.

Comment: it looks like you're trying to apply math operations to strings hence it erroring

Comment: If you could give use some insight into what Átomo.txt contains, that would be helpful.

Comment: That is not a question. Please formulate your problem and add a clear title.

Answer (score 1):

`colunas` is read from the file as a string, and splitting it will result in a list of strings. If you want to use them as numbers, you'll have to explicitly convert them. E.g.:

```
coluna_limpa = [float(x) for x in colunas.strip().split("\t")]
```

Comment: that worked! thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to subtract strings, to convert from string to integer, use `int()`.

```
d = dist(int(deltaX[0]), int(deltaX[9]),
         int(deltaY[0]), int(deltaY[9]),
         int(deltaZ[0]), int(deltaZ[9]))
```

or if your numbers are floats, use `float()`.

```
d = dist(float(deltaX[0]), float(deltaX[9]),
         float(deltaY[0]), float(deltaY[9]),
         float(deltaZ[0]), float(deltaZ[9]))
```

Comment: I just added that while you wrote the comment :)